# How phasset get video url?

Tags: swift, url, video, uicollectionview, avplayer

Show all videos in camera roll and displaying them in UICollectionView.

How phasset get video url?

```
    var videos: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!

    fileprivate func fetchVideos() {
        print("fetch Videos")
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false) ]
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
        videos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
        print(videos)
        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)

        let asset = videos!.object(at: indexPath.row)
                   ???

    }
```

CollectionViewCellHeader ;

```
let fileUrl = ""

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    let videoURL = "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"

    let fileUrl = NSURL(string: videoURL) as! URL


    var aPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fileUrl)
    let moviePlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    moviePlayerController.player = aPlayer
    moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:frame.size.width, height:frame.height)
    moviePlayerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue
    moviePlayerController.view.sizeToFit()
    moviePlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false
    moviePlayerController.player?.play()
    addSubview(moviePlayerController.view)

}
```

How do I get the selected video URL?
How can I use the `requestPlayerItem()` method?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the selected video URL

You don’t. And you don’t need it. The PHImageManager gives you the video directly from the PHAsset, in various forms, depending what you want to do with it.

For example, if your goal is to play the video, call this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616958-requestplayeritem

Comment: The link is to the docs. Read the docs. Obey. Once you have an AVPlayerItem, you can play it. I’m not going to write your code for you; indeed, you did not even say what exactly you want to do with the video.  I answered the question you asked. Try what I said.

Comment: That doesn’t matter. You thought you needed the URL of the video. I answered that you don’t need it and I told you why.

Comment: There are multiple reasons why someone would need the video URL. This is a classic developer answer to tell someone they don't need the video URL, lol. But thank you for answering anyways

Comment: @BennyTheNerd It's just a fact. There is _no_ "URL" for a video in the photo library in any traditional sense. The PHAsset is the video's "address" within the database.

Comment: try foundPHAsset.localIdentifier.asURL()

Comment: @BennyTheNerd The `localIdentifier` is indeed the unique identifier for the PHAsset (as I have explained [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A341994+is%3Aa+code%3AlocalIdentifier)). But it is not a URL, and it has no `asURL()` method. If you need to hang on to the "address" of a PHAsset, you store the `localIdentifier` and stop.